# Postorder, preorder, inorder traversals, Binary Search Tree

Tags: tree-traversal

Consider the following tree structure.

```
    A
   / \
  B   C
 / \   \
D   E   F
```

In what order will the nodes be visited using a postorder, a preorder, and an inorder traversal?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: *sniff sniff*... you smell that?  It smells like homework

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this is not about programming

Comment: @rayryeng, it is about terminology of programming.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky - If that's the case, then this should be asked on Programmer's Stack Exchange: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hey, reopen it, I learned someting new here. This is good for half-baked programmers like me. This is not a philosophical question for programmers.stackexchange.com, this is a concrete question about algorithm terminology.

Answer (score 9):

I find that it helps to think of `postorder`, `preorder`, and `inorder` as recursive algorithms.

### Postorder traversal

Recursively, this is **left, right, self**. In other words, do the traversal for the left subtree, then do the traversal for the right subtree, and only then visit the current node. The base case would be when the node has no children.

For this example:

Answer: `D, E, B, F, C, A`

Explanation:

1. Start at node A. Evaluate left subtree. At node B. Evaluate left subtree. At node D. No children -> **visit D**.
2. Go back to B. Evaluate right subtree. At node E. No children -> **visit E**.
3. Go back to B. **Visit B**.
4. Go back to A. Evaluate right subtree. At node C. No left subtree, so evaluate right subtree. At node F. No children -> **visit F**.
5. Go back to C. **Visit C**.
6. Go back to A. **Visit A**

### Preorder traversal

Recursively, this is **self, left, right**.

See if you can get the answer yourself using the logic of the `postorder traversal`.

### Inorder traversal

Recursively, this is **left, self, right**.

See if you can get the answer yourself using the logic of the `postorder traversal`.

### If you wish to check your work,

the `Preorder traversal` would be `A, B, D, E, C, F` and the `Inorder traversal` would be `D, B, E, A, C, F`.